# What footswitch can I use on my Ammoon Stereo Looper pedal?

Tags: electric-guitar, effects-pedal, electronics, looper-pedals

I recently bought [this Ammoon looper pedal](https://www.tonebox.com/pedal/ammoon-stereo-looper). For the price, it has a great quality. However, I want to use a footswitch on it.

As you can see [on this picture](https://nitrocdn.com/fUwjwGymwtZbiICpqXJIDHxKOunsHQWm/assets/static/source/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/a4afb700fc0ad965e6d0a1f953c19fd3.61ljaYlJYgL.jpg), on the left side (amp side) of the pedal in an input jack for a foot switch. You can supposedly plug in a footswitch and press it to replace the rotating knob, which can allow you to cycle between loops for instance. This is the use case I am looking for: if I'm playing a song that has a variation in theme, I would love to be able to switch between my loop 1 and 2 using foot control (like I'm currently doing using the knob).

I tried three footswitches that I had in store:

- a Bespeco piano sustain pedal,
- an unbranded sustain pedal,
- the footswitch of my Marshall amp (that has two buttons: "channel" and "effect").

None of them worked: when I plug the footswitch, the pedal cycles two loops back. Suppose it is currently playing the recorded loop n°5, well, it will quickly display 5-4-3 and play loop n°3. The same happens when I unplug the footswitch.

I tried looking it up but I can't find anything since Ammoon is not really a huge brand (probably a dropshipping brand, tbh). Does anyone have any input concerning the kind of footswitch that I can use to cycle between loops?

Comment: It's a momentary pedal - so a piano sustain should work, but the instructions say it needs a 1/4" *stereo* jack. It could be that you need to be *very* quick tapping it - holding for a moment longer lets it scroll back too far. Pedals with a stereo jack are capable of half-pedalling, not sure Bespecco does that. I'd be plugging a TRS jack in, with three bare wire ends, and touching them together to see what happens then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eighth page of the manual describes necessary specifications of the foot controller.

[image]

Typical amp footswitch using latching switches certainly isn't a good replacement. Typical sustain pedal uses a mono plug which permanently shorts ring and sleeve, and apparently your unit is not happy with it either.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you. I can't believe I missed this. I'll try to find an appropriate footswitch.